Convert (ImageMagick) ignores quality level setting when converting to webp in Mint 22
I've been using convert to recompress images to webp for publication. My command line is:
convert -quality 70 input.jpg test.webp

This works in Mint 20 (ImageMagick 6.9.10-23), but in Mint 22 (ImageMagick 6.9.12-98) the -quality flag seems to do nothing at all. Whether I say -quality 1 or -quality 99, I get the same result. However, -quality 100 produces a gigantic (I assume uncompressed image)

Would sound like a regression that you would want to report to Mint as bug.
Anyways, you could avoid using convert for compression jobs. First of all, ImageMagick themselves are in the process of deprecating the convert standalone tool, in favor of magick. (Try magick convert …, maybe the regression is just in the command line parsing of convert, then that'd be an easy fix.)
On my machine, GraphicsMagick is measurably faster (~10%) than ImageMagick (didn't profile why, it's a 20 years old fork of ImageMagick with a slightly nicer command line interface and a few security exploits fewer, so maybe it's just less historical cruft?), and its
gm convert -quality 70 large_input_image.jpeg out.webp

seems to produce significantly larger output than -quality 1 and significantly smaller output than -quality 100.
It's available on Mint 22 via sudo apt install graphicsmagick.

Thanks, that works.
